# splitting a dynamic string to store in separate variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic string like below one getting from server.it may be more than 2.

```
[{text :'AC Maintenance today ', value:16.00, color: '#DEE3E8'},{text :'test3', value:150.00, color: '#5A0C55'}]
```

How to get each values in a separate  js variable.
for eg

```
var text = ["AC Maintenance today","test3"];
var value = [16.00,150.00];
var color = ["#DEE3E8","#5A0C55"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var values = [{text :'AC Maintenance today ', value:16.00, color: '#DEE3E8'},{text :'test3', value:150.00, color: '#5A0C55'}]

const text = values.map((v) => v.text)
const value= values.map((v) => v.value)
const color= values.map((v) => v.color)
```